# Visual Studio ClickOnce Problem

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I'm getting the following error when i send a finished program to a client in a ClickOnce deployment setup.

[image: An error ocurred while downloading a required file. You may retry downloading the file or cancel setup.]
Yet when i try to execute it on my PC, it runs perfectly, i also tried the same program on my laptop and no problems. Yet he has tried to execute this in 5 different PC and get's the same error on each.

He also gets the following error when he click on details.

> ---------------------------begins:
>
> PLATFORM VERSION INFO Windows :
>   6.0.6001.65536 (Win32NT) Common Language Runtime : 2.0.50727.3603
>   System.Deployment.dll : 2.0.50727.3053
>   (netfxsp.050727-3000) mscorwks.dll :
>   2.0.50727.3603 (GDR.050727-3600) dfdll.dll : 2.0.50727.3053
>   (netfxsp.050727-3000) dfshim.dll :
>   2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>
> SOURCES Deployment url :
>   file:///C:/Users/MAIN-HD2/AppData/Local/Temp/7zO48D2.tmp/Desktop%20Manager.application
>
> ERROR SUMMARY Below is a summary of
>   the errors, details of these errors
>   are listed later in the log.
>   * Activation of C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application resulted in
>   exception. Following failure messages
>   were detected:
>   + Downloading file:///C:/Users/MAIN-HD2/AppData/Local/Temp/7zO48D2.tmp/Desktop
>   Manager.application did not succeed.
>   + Could not find file 'C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application'.
>   + Could not find file 'C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application'.
>   + Could not find file 'C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application'.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE
>   SUMMARY No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS There were no warnings during
>   this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>   * [9/9/2010 2:21:17 PM] : Activation of
>   C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS Following errors were
>   detected during this operation.
>   * [9/9/2010 2:21:17 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException
>   (Unknown subtype)
>   - Downloading file:///C:/Users/MAIN-HD2/AppData/Local/Temp/7zO48D2.tmp/Desktop
>   Manager.application did not succeed.
>   - Source: System.Deployment
>   - Stack trace: at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next) at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>   at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>   subState) at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri&
>   sourceUri, String targetPath,
>   IDownloadNotification notification,
>   DownloadOptions options,
>   ServerInformation& serverInformation)
>   at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore
>   subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile&
>   tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState,
>   IDownloadNotification notification,
>   DownloadOptions options,
>   ServerInformation& serverInformation)
>   at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore
>   subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile&
>   tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState,
>   IDownloadNotification notification,
>   DownloadOptions options) at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut,
>   String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension,
>   BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl) at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)
>   --- Inner Exception --- System.Net.WebException
>   - Could not find file 'C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application'.
>   - Source: System
>   - Stack trace: at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)
>   --- Inner Exception --- System.Net.WebException
>   - Could not find file 'C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application'.
>   - Source: System
>   - Stack trace: at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest
>   request, Uri uri, FileAccess access,
>   Boolean asyncHint) at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object
>   state)
>   --- Inner Exception --- System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   - Could not find file 'C:\Users\MAIN-HD2\AppData\Local\Temp\7zO48D2.tmp\Desktop
>   Manager.application'.
>   - Source: mscorlib
>   - Stack trace: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
>   Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, Boolean useAsync) at
>   System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest
>   request, String path, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare sharing,
>   Int32 length, Boolean async) at
>   System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest
>   request, Uri uri, FileAccess access,
>   Boolean asyncHint)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS No
>   transaction information is available.
>
> ------------------------ends

Please any help would be greatly appreciated, cause I'm loosing my mind over this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this... this error occurs when the pc you are installing a ClickOnce Application doesn't have all requirements to run a .net framework application, and is not correctly connected to the internet. It tries to download the necessary files, but fails.